# check file size returns error:Path must be a string without null bytes when check file size

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am trying to check the size of file using file-system package in express js but i will get the following error

> Path must be a string without null bytes when check file size

```
fs.stat(req.files.image.data, function(err, stat) {
            if(err) {
                // handle error
                console.log(err)
            }
            console.log(stat);
        });
```

However `req.files.image` returns correct ouptut.

```
> { name: 'Clocktower_Panorama_20080622_20mb (1).jpg',   data: <Buffer
> ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 48 00 48 00 00 ff e1 00
> 80 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 05 01 12 00 03 00 00
> 00 01 00 01 ... >,   encoding: '7bit',   mimetype: 'image/jpeg',   mv:
> [Function: mv] }
```

Comment: You want to check the _name_, not the _data_ …

Comment: Starnge!! how can i get file size from name??

Comment: You are trying to pass the binary image data to stat, which makes no sense. Pass the name instead of data.

Comment: I've tried but i will get path not found error it requires the full path but the file is uploaded from the user

Comment: Well then prefix the name with your upload path …

Comment: I never storing the file instead directly upload to AWS s3

Comment: Well then what do you want to call stat on?

Comment: to get the size of the file i would like to set maximum upload size to 15 mb

Comment: That does not answer the question. stat gets information about local files. You say you don’t have a local file(?). So - what do you want to call stat on then?

Comment: Ohh i didn't know about it but how can i get the size before upload

Comment: You can not get it before the upload to your system, because the code you have shown works _after_ the file was uploaded to your system. // All the data you need should be there already, I think. You should have a data structure similar to what https://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads shows (might perhaps differ slightly for newer node versions).

Comment: Thanks but its old  also it dosen't talk about the file size

Comment: Of course it has the file size, what do you think `size: 11885` means? And it has a getter `length` also. If you are using a different node version, then I suggest you go check the documentation for that first of all, to see what properties and methods are available for uploaded files.